# How to know the number of slaves executed

Tags: hadoop, count, mapreduce, cpu-word, slave

I have a question about map/reduce excution.
I have a code of wordcount I execute it.(I have 2 slaves and 1 master). How do I know that the slave 2 is executed? How can I do something like `println` in console to get informed when the slave is executed?

Well I tried this astuce in the part of function map:

```
String ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress().toString();
```

I use the IP and I am sending it as a key (and the value is  `new intWritable`
so the reduce receive the IP of the slave that execute the map code and write it in the output file. But this wasn't successful, because it wrote the IP address of the slave 1 or slave 2, but not the adresses of 2 slaves and I use the:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(link,job.getConfiguration());
```

for distribution of all the file at all the slaves (not a portion of file to each slave).

and finally I get:

node manager log:

```
2015-05-17 22:35:52,855 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: 
Auth successful for appattempt_1431892621101_0005_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-05-17 22:35:54,294 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Start request for container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002 by user hduser
2015-05-17 22:35:54,579 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Creating a new application reference for app application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:35:54,707 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=hduser   IP=192.168.1.11 OPERATION=Start Container Request   TARGET=ContainerManageImpl  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1431892621101_0005    CONTAINERID=container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002
2015-05-17 22:35:55,092 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1431892621101_0005 transitioned from NEW to INITING
2015-05-17 22:35:55,102 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Adding container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002 to application application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:35:55,145 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1431892621101_0005 transitioned from INITING to RUNNING
2015-05-17 22:35:55,642 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002 transitioned from NEW to LOCALIZING
2015-05-17 22:35:55,658 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_INIT for appId application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:35:55,663 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event APPLICATION_INIT for appId application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:35:55,663 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got APPLICATION_INIT for service mapreduce_shuffle
2015-05-17 22:35:55,759 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler: Added token for job_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:35:55,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://master:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1431892621101_0005/job.jar transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
2015-05-17 22:35:55,909 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://master:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1431892621101_0005/job.xml transitioned from INIT to DOWNLOADING
2015-05-17 22:35:56,085 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Created localizer for container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002
2015-05-17 22:35:56,734 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Writing credentials to the nmPrivate file /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002.tokens. Credentials list: 
2015-05-17 22:36:00,700 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Initializing user hduser
2015-05-17 22:36:01,816 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Copying from /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/nmPrivate/container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002.tokens to /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1431892621101_0005/container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002.tokens
2015-05-17 22:36:01,865 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Localizer CWD set to /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1431892621101_0005 = file:/tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:36:22,696 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://master:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1431892621101_0005/job.jar(->/tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1431892621101_0005/filecache/10/job.jar) transitioned from DOWNLOADING to LOCALIZED
2015-05-17 22:36:22,979 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.LocalizedResource: Resource hdfs://master:54310/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hduser/.staging/job_1431892621101_0005/job.xml(->/tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1431892621101_0005/filecache/11/job.xml) transitioned from DOWNLOADING to LOCALIZED
2015-05-17 22:36:22,979 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002 transitioned from LOCALIZING to LOCALIZED
2015-05-17 22:36:23,752 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002 transitioned from LOCALIZED to RUNNING
2015-05-17 22:36:23,902 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: launchContainer: [bash, /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1431892621101_0005/container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002/default_container_executor.sh]
2015-05-17 22:36:26,604 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Starting resource-monitoring for container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002
2015-05-17 22:36:29,051 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7030 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002: 28.3 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:36:36,703 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7030 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002: 35.3 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:36:42,008 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7030 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002: 66.4 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:36:50,807 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7030 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002: 78.4 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:36:56,039 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7030 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002: 87.3 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:37:13,734 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7030 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002: 233.7 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:37:17,816 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1431892621101_0005_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-05-17 22:37:18,024 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Stopping container with container Id: container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002
2015-05-17 22:37:18,094 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=hduser   IP=192.168.1.11 OPERATION=Stop Container Request    TARGET=ContainerManageImpl  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1431892621101_0005    CONTAINERID=container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002
2015-05-17 22:37:18,130 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002 transitioned from RUNNING to KILLING
2015-05-17 22:37:18,149 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002
2015-05-17 22:37:20,943 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002 is : 143
2015-05-17 22:37:21,116 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7030 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002: 0B of 1 GB physical memory used; 0B of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:37:21,721 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002 transitioned from KILLING to CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL
2015-05-17 22:37:21,749 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=hduser   OPERATION=Container Finished - Killed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1431892621101_0005    CONTAINERID=container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002
2015-05-17 22:37:21,749 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002 transitioned from CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL to DONE
2015-05-17 22:37:21,750 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Removing container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002 from application application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:37:21,769 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:37:21,914 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1431892621101_0005/container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002
2015-05-17 22:37:22,521 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1431892621101_0005_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-05-17 22:37:22,637 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Start request for container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003 by user hduser
2015-05-17 22:37:22,639 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=hduser   IP=192.168.1.11 OPERATION=Start Container Request   TARGET=ContainerManageImpl  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1431892621101_0005    CONTAINERID=container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003
2015-05-17 22:37:22,639 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Adding container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003 to application application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:37:22,708 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003 transitioned from NEW to LOCALIZING
2015-05-17 22:37:22,709 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_INIT for appId application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:37:22,709 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event APPLICATION_INIT for appId application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:37:22,709 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got APPLICATION_INIT for service mapreduce_shuffle
2015-05-17 22:37:22,710 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler: Added token for job_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:37:22,712 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003 transitioned from LOCALIZING to LOCALIZED
2015-05-17 22:37:23,245 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003 transitioned from LOCALIZED to RUNNING
2015-05-17 22:37:23,294 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: launchContainer: [bash, /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1431892621101_0005/container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003/default_container_executor.sh]
2015-05-17 22:37:24,119 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Starting resource-monitoring for container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003
2015-05-17 22:37:24,119 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Stopping resource-monitoring for container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002
2015-05-17 22:37:25,044 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Removed completed containers from NM context: [container_1431892621101_0005_01_000002]
2015-05-17 22:37:27,019 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 27.4 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:37:32,749 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 43.8 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.7 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:37:39,417 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 75 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:37:46,295 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 104.5 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:37:48,835 INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler: Setting connection close header...
2015-05-17 22:37:52,871 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 147.5 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:37:56,163 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 151.8 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:38:33,363 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 157.2 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:38:40,907 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 157.1 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:38:57,551 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 161.5 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:39:02,314 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 164.0 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:39:07,150 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 164.0 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:39:10,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 164.0 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:39:13,957 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 161.4 MB of 1 GB physical memory used; 1.8 GB of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:39:16,564 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1431892621101_0005_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
2015-05-17 22:39:16,794 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Stopping container with container Id: container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003
2015-05-17 22:39:16,795 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003 transitioned from RUNNING to KILLING
2015-05-17 22:39:16,795 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch: Cleaning up container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003
2015-05-17 22:39:16,796 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=hduser   IP=192.168.1.11 OPERATION=Stop Container Request    TARGET=ContainerManageImpl  RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1431892621101_0005    CONTAINERID=container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003
2015-05-17 22:39:18,989 WARN org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Exit code from container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003 is : 143
2015-05-17 22:39:19,847 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003 transitioned from KILLING to CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL
2015-05-17 22:39:19,852 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NMAuditLogger: USER=hduser   OPERATION=Container Finished - Killed   TARGET=ContainerImpl    RESULT=SUCCESS  APPID=application_1431892621101_0005    CONTAINERID=container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003
2015-05-17 22:39:19,852 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.Container: Container container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003 transitioned from CONTAINER_CLEANEDUP_AFTER_KILL to DONE
2015-05-17 22:39:19,852 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Removing container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003 from application application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:39:19,852 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event CONTAINER_STOP for appId application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:39:19,954 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1431892621101_0005/container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003
2015-05-17 22:39:19,983 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Memory usage of ProcessTree 7093 for container-id container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003: 0B of 1 GB physical memory used; 0B of 2.1 GB virtual memory used
2015-05-17 22:39:22,984 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Stopping resource-monitoring for container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003
2015-05-17 22:39:29,850 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.NodeStatusUpdaterImpl: Removed completed containers from NM context: [container_1431892621101_0005_01_000003]
2015-05-17 22:39:30,206 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1431892621101_0005 transitioned from RUNNING to APPLICATION_RESOURCES_CLEANINGUP
2015-05-17 22:39:30,264 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.AuxServices: Got event APPLICATION_STOP for appId application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:39:30,272 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: Deleting absolute path : /tmp/hadoop-hduser/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1431892621101_0005
2015-05-17 22:39:30,289 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.application.Application: Application application_1431892621101_0005 transitioned from APPLICATION_RESOURCES_CLEANINGUP to FINISHED
2015-05-17 22:39:30,289 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.loghandler.NonAggregatingLogHandler: Scheduling Log Deletion for application: application_1431892621101_0005, with delay of 10800 seconds
```

I expect that I will find for example the number of `nodemanager` instances that execute the code in this precedent part but I didn't.

*How do I know the number of slaves that are executed in my code?*
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if you simply need to use properly LOGFJ, but, if this is not that case, you should look for all the logs that slave's create, because the output that you show to us here, doesn't have all the information present on those logs. And, if this isn't useful, at least we can drop that option and wait that other user's tell you another alternative.

Comment: i lock in the log files ... yes it is all normal i will modify my question and i put the log fil of (node manager)... it is all normal it is show that the node manager ana data node work in the same time  when i execute my code ...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

dataNode logs:

```
enter code here
2015-05-17 22:15:53,749 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741854_1030 src: /192.168.1.10:53005 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:16:02,962 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 329ms (threshold=300ms)
2015-05-17 22:16:19,755 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 303ms (threshold=300ms)
2015-05-17 22:17:00,801 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53005, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 57614344, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1317607313_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741854_1030, duration: 58914540985
2015-05-17 22:17:00,823 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741854_1030, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:17:07,237 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741854_1030 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741854 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:17:07,325 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741854_1030 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741854
2015-05-17 22:24:31,972 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741855_1031 src: /192.168.1.10:53023 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:25:29,693 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53023, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 57614412, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_553195046_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741855_1031, duration: 57499963690
2015-05-17 22:25:29,712 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741855_1031, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:25:30,882 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741856_1032 src: /192.168.1.10:53028 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:25:31,043 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53028, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 131, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_553195046_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741856_1032, duration: 26027070
2015-05-17 22:25:31,045 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741856_1032, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:25:31,162 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741857_1033 src: /192.168.1.10:53030 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:25:31,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53030, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 13, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_553195046_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741857_1033, duration: 62104463
2015-05-17 22:25:31,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741857_1033, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:25:32,384 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741858_1034 src: /192.168.1.10:53032 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:25:32,642 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53032, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 88165, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_553195046_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741858_1034, duration: 198784861
2015-05-17 22:25:32,642 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741858_1034, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:26:03,671 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741859_1035 src: /192.168.1.11:44921 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:26:03,870 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.11:44921, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 104903, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_589847681_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741859_1035, duration: 141461930
2015-05-17 22:26:03,871 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741859_1035, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-05-17 22:26:11,276 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741860_1036 src: /192.168.1.11:44928 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:26:18,166 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.11:44928, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 33241, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_589847681_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741860_1036, duration: 6865081449
2015-05-17 22:26:18,166 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741860_1036, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-05-17 22:26:18,320 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741861_1037 src: /192.168.1.11:44935 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:26:18,374 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.11:44935, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 347, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_589847681_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741861_1037, duration: 50009828
2015-05-17 22:26:18,375 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741861_1037, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-05-17 22:26:18,841 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741862_1038 src: /192.168.1.11:44938 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:26:18,900 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.11:44938, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 33241, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_589847681_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741862_1038, duration: 53415933
2015-05-17 22:26:18,900 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741862_1038, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-05-17 22:26:19,169 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741863_1039 src: /192.168.1.11:44940 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:26:19,329 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.11:44940, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 104903, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_589847681_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741863_1039, duration: 157935747
2015-05-17 22:26:19,331 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741863_1039, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-05-17 22:26:23,457 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741856_1032 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741856 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:26:23,515 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741856_1032 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741856
2015-05-17 22:26:23,515 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741857_1033 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741857 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:26:23,603 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741857_1033 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741857
2015-05-17 22:26:23,677 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741858_1034 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741858 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:26:23,678 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741859_1035 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741859 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:26:23,680 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741860_1036 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741860 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:26:23,680 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741858_1034 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741858
2015-05-17 22:26:23,681 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741859_1035 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741859
2015-05-17 22:26:23,682 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741855_1031 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741855 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:26:23,683 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741860_1036 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741860
2015-05-17 22:26:23,688 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741855_1031 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741855
2015-05-17 22:31:18,177 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741864_1040 src: /192.168.1.10:53045 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:31:18,411 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53045, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 2, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-572045485_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741864_1040, duration: 120795963
2015-05-17 22:31:18,412 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741864_1040, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:33:03,737 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741865_1041 src: /192.168.1.10:53053 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:33:03,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53053, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 2, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-947295319_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741865_1041, duration: 138647149
2015-05-17 22:33:03,895 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741865_1041, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:34:37,656 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741866_1042 src: /192.168.1.10:53059 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:35:35,213 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53059, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 57614412, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1837746633_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741866_1042, duration: 57228181985
2015-05-17 22:35:35,282 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741866_1042, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:35:36,863 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741867_1043 src: /192.168.1.10:53064 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:35:36,943 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53064, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 126, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1837746633_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741867_1043, duration: 24430351
2015-05-17 22:35:36,943 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741867_1043, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:35:37,104 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741868_1044 src: /192.168.1.10:53066 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:35:37,266 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53066, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 26, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1837746633_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741868_1044, duration: 145913793
2015-05-17 22:35:37,267 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741868_1044, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:35:38,798 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741869_1045 src: /192.168.1.10:53068 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:35:39,276 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53068, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 88156, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1837746633_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741869_1045, duration: 190623489
2015-05-17 22:35:39,278 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741869_1045, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:35:48,707 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741870_1046 src: /192.168.1.11:44948 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:35:48,956 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.11:44948, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 104894, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-824185019_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741870_1046, duration: 178516552
2015-05-17 22:35:48,958 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741870_1046, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-05-17 22:37:19,135 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741871_1047 src: /192.168.1.11:44955 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:37:51,956 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741872_1048 src: /192.168.1.10:53088 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:38:40,341 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 42910ms (threshold=300ms)
2015-05-17 22:38:40,842 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 493ms (threshold=300ms)
2015-05-17 22:38:41,809 WARN org.apache.hadoop.util.JvmPauseMonitor: Detected pause in JVM or host machine (eg GC): pause of approximately 42670ms
GC pool 'PS Scavenge' had collection(s): count=1 time=42530ms
2015-05-17 22:38:41,904 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 495ms (threshold=300ms)
2015-05-17 22:38:50,682 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write data to disk cost:382ms (threshold=300ms)
2015-05-17 22:38:58,498 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write data to disk cost:346ms (threshold=300ms)
2015-05-17 22:39:03,675 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Slow BlockReceiver write packet to mirror took 407ms (threshold=300ms)
2015-05-17 22:39:15,336 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.10:53088, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 37785075, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_attempt_1431892621101_0005_r_000000_0_-581669036_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741872_1048, duration: 82970475818
2015-05-17 22:39:15,346 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741872_1048, type=HAS_DOWNSTREAM_IN_PIPELINE terminating
2015-05-17 22:39:16,181 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolSliceScanner: Verification succeeded for BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741852_1028
2015-05-17 22:39:16,236 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolSliceScanner: Verification succeeded for BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741851_1027
2015-05-17 22:39:16,313 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolSliceScanner: Verification succeeded for BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741853_1029
2015-05-17 22:39:19,173 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.11:44955, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 33639, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-824185019_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741871_1047, duration: 119891168848
2015-05-17 22:39:19,174 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741871_1047, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-05-17 22:39:20,113 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741873_1049 src: /192.168.1.11:44963 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:39:20,135 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.11:44963, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 350, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-824185019_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741873_1049, duration: 20566418
2015-05-17 22:39:20,137 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741873_1049, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-05-17 22:39:20,455 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741874_1050 src: /192.168.1.11:44966 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:39:20,528 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.11:44966, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 33639, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-824185019_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741874_1050, duration: 68722185
2015-05-17 22:39:20,528 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741874_1050, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-05-17 22:39:20,655 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Receiving BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741875_1051 src: /192.168.1.11:44968 dest: /192.168.1.10:50010
2015-05-17 22:39:20,779 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.clienttrace: src: /192.168.1.11:44968, dest: /192.168.1.10:50010, bytes: 104894, op: HDFS_WRITE, cliID: DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-824185019_1, offset: 0, srvID: 555ac87e-c981-4e93-866a-42f33be6ff6e, blockid: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741875_1051, duration: 117317991
2015-05-17 22:39:20,850 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: PacketResponder: BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741875_1051, type=LAST_IN_PIPELINE, downstreams=0:[] terminating
2015-05-17 22:39:21,674 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolSliceScanner: Verification succeeded for BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741870_1046
2015-05-17 22:39:21,790 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolSliceScanner: Verification succeeded for BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741863_1039
2015-05-17 22:39:21,874 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BlockPoolSliceScanner: Verification succeeded for BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808:blk_1073741867_1043
2015-05-17 22:39:25,480 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741866_1042 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741866 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:39:25,481 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741867_1043 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741867 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:39:25,481 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741868_1044 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741868 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:39:25,481 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741869_1045 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741869 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:39:25,482 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741870_1046 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741870 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:39:25,482 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Scheduling blk_1073741871_1047 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741871 for deletion
2015-05-17 22:39:25,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741866_1042 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741866
2015-05-17 22:39:25,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741867_1043 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741867
2015-05-17 22:39:25,542 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741868_1044 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741868
2015-05-17 22:39:25,554 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741869_1045 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741869
2015-05-17 22:39:25,554 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741870_1046 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_1073741870
2015-05-17 22:39:25,554 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetAsyncDiskService: Deleted BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808 blk_1073741871_1047 file /usr/local/tmp/hdfs/datanode/current/BP-567696754-192.168.1.10-1431878010808/current/finalized/subdir0/subdir0/blk_107374187
```

Comment: This is part of your original question! It shouldn't be here, as an answer!

Comment: Yes but i coudnt do that because the number of character is limited in my part of question

Comment: @chomp hello can we extract the information of slave from this logs?

Comment: you can see the interaction between 192.168.1.10 and 192.168.1.11, but i don't know if that's what your are looking for.

Comment: i try job history but the link didnt work(in the web site(master:8088))
and from the input of @IP the supposed result is the output file contains the 2 IP of slaves.but no it just contain one.that means i think that the program excute just in one slave and thats not a good for me .why it just excuted in one slave??how force hadoop to excute my program in all slaves.?i think the cause is the input file (1.8MB) hadoop look from the size of file that one slave is Enough ,but how i forced to do that ?is there any modification in XML files or in the code shoud do it to excute code in all slaves.

Comment: when i make the output of map is the IP of the machine that excute the code..the supposed result that the reducer receaive the IPs of machines with values of course but in my case no it just receive one IP . @chomp